# How to interpret source map mappings?

Tags: css, sass, source-maps

Let's say I have this stylesheet:

```
.d1
    width: 10px
    .d2
        width: 20px
```

It results in the following css code (with `nested` output style):

```
.d1 {
  width: 10px; }
  .d1 .d2 {
    width: 20px; }
```

Source map (`v3`) contains the following mappings:

```
AAAA,AAAA,GAAG,CAAC;EACA,KAAK,EAAE,IAAK,GAES;EAHzB,AAEI,GAFD,CAEC,GAAG,CAAC;IACA,KAAK,EAAE,IAAK,GAAG
```

After decoding it with [this service](http://www.murzwin.com/base64vlq.html), I got:

```
([0,0](#0)=>[0,0]) | ([0,0](#0)=>[0,0]) | ([0,3](#0)=>[0,3]) | ([0,4](#0)=>[0,4])
([1,4](#0)=>[1,2]) | ([1,9](#0)=>[1,7]) | ([1,11](#0)=>[1,9]) | ([1,16](#0)=>[1,13]) | ([3,25](#0)=>[1,16])
([0,0](#0)=>[2,2]) | ([2,4](#0)=>[2,2]) | ([0,3](#0)=>[2,5]) | ([2,4](#0)=>[2,6]) | ([2,7](#0)=>[2,9]) | ([2,8](#0)=>[2,10])
([3,8](#0)=>[3,4]) | ([3,13](#0)=>[3,9]) | ([3,15](#0)=>[3,11]) | ([3,20](#0)=>[3,15]) | ([3,23](#0)=>[3,18])
```

Source was generated in a [similar fashion](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1813) with `node-sass` (`libsass`).

My understaning is that those are pairs of points from original and resulting file. But let's take for example last pair from the second line: `([3,25](#0)=>[1,16])`. Row 3 column 25? That's kind of unexpected, don't you think?

Am I doing it wrong? Or source map is incorrect? Can you suggest the way to generate correct source map, if so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a [great tool](http://libsass.ocbnet.ch/srcmap/), that you can use not only with `libsass` as explained [here](http://libsass.ocbnet.ch/srcmap/about.html).

Do note, you need a file with source map embedded as a multiline comment and with `sourcesContent` field in it, like this one:

```
.d1 {
  width: 10px; }
  .d1 .d2 {
    width: 20px; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJtYXBwaW5ncyI6IkFBQUEsR0FBSTtFQUNBLEtBQUssRUFBRSxJQUFJO0VBQ1gsT0FBSTtJQUNBLEtBQUssRUFBRSxJQUFJIiwic291cmNlcyI6WyIxLnNjc3MiXSwic291cmNlc0NvbnRlbnQiOlsiLmQxIHtcbiAgICB3aWR0aDogMTBweDtcbiAgICAuZDIge1xuICAgICAgICB3aWR0aDogMjBweDtcbiAgICB9XG59XG4iXSwibmFtZXMiOltdLCJmaWxlIjoiMS5jc3MifQ== */
```

You just paste it into Output field, click Analyze, and you're all set. It doesn't matter what was in Input field before that. It gets replaced with content from source map. Use arrow keys to switch between mappings.

Let's examine how you do it with ruby's `sass` gem:

`Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'sass'
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "convert-source-map": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

`1.scss`:

```
.d1 {
    width: 10px;
    .d2 {
        width: 20px;
    }
}
```

`1.js`:

```
var convert = require('convert-source-map');
var fs = require('fs');
console.log(
    convert.fromJSON(
            fs.readFileSync('1.css.map')
    ).toComment()
    .replace(/^\/\//, '/*')
    .replace(/$/, ' */')
);
```

Then

```
$ bundle install && npm i
$ rm -f 1.css* && bundle exec sass --sourcemap=inline 1.scss 1.css
$ cat 1.css | head -n -1 && node 1.js
.d1 {
  width: 10px; }
  .d1 .d2 {
    width: 20px; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJtYXBwaW5ncyI6IkFBQUEsR0FBSTtFQUNBLEtBQUssRUFBRSxJQUFJO0VBQ1gsT0FBSTtJQUNBLEtBQUssRUFBRSxJQUFJIiwic291cmNlcyI6WyIxLnNjc3MiXSwibmFtZXMiOltdLCJmaWxlIjoiMS5jc3MifQ== */
```

Put it into Output field and that's it.

The workflow is a bit involved. But that's far more painless way to inspect source maps, then doing it "by hand." I'm talking from my own experience here :)

**In case, you've got source map as json**, like:

```
{ version: 3,
  sourceRoot: '/path/to/dir',
  sources: [ '1.css' ],
  sourcesContent: [ 'body {\n    background: #ddd;\n}\ndiv {\n    width: 100px;\n    height: 100px;\n    margin: auto;\n    background: #666;\n}\n' ],
  names: [],
  mappings: 'AAAA,AAAA,IAAI,AAAC,CACD,UAAU,CAAE,IAAI,CACnB,AACD,AAAA,GAAG,AAAC,CACA,KAAK,CAAE,KAAK,CACZ,MAAM,CAAE,KAAK,CACb,MAAM,CAAE,IAAI,CACZ,UAAU,CAAE,IAAI,CACnB' }
```

You can convert it into a comment as follows:

```
var convertSourceMap = require('convert-source-map')
console.log(convertSourceMap.fromJSON(mapAsAString).toComment({multiline: true}));
```

P.S. Here are [some](http://paulirish.github.io/source-map-visualization/) [more](https://sokra.github.io/source-map-visualization/) [tools](http://sourcemapper.qfox.nl/). And [introduction to source maps](https://qfox.nl/weblog/281). Also, [`sourcemap-codec` package](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/sourcemap-codec) may come in handy.